# Rascal - Rewrite AST using a visitor

Tags: rascal

I am trying to rewrite all the different Types in the AST to a single type (like char() for example). So far I am able to find the types, but I cannot seem to find a way to rewrite them.

So the idea is to do something like this (this example doesn't work ofcourse):

```
visit (ast) {
    case \Type(_) => \Type(char())
}
```

Can someone please help me, and tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to remember is that you can't change values in Rascal using side effects: when you change a value, what you get instead is a new instance of that datatype with the changes, but the old instance still remains (if anything refers to it). When you do a `visit`, you get back a new instance of the datatype with any changes you've made, but you need to assign this somewhere or it will be lost. Here is an example illustrating this:

```
rascal>data A = a() | b();
ok

rascal>data A = c(A a);
ok

rascal>myA = c(a());
A: c(a())

rascal>visit(myA) { case a() => b() }
A: c(b())

rascal>myA;
A: c(a())

rascal>myA = visit(myA) { case a() => b() }
A: c(b())

rascal>myA;
A: c(b())
```

As you can see, with the first `visit` the `a()` inside `c(a())` is changed to a `b()`, but `myA` is still what it was before. Once you assign the value of the `visit` into `myA`, the change is preserved.